# Directx version is 11 but DDI version is 9Ex?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, display-driver, directx

I am using windows 7 as my VirtualBox VM. So today I do a clean install of Windows 7 on my VM. Set up browsers, install extra software, etc... Then I tried to install the Directx End-User Runtime, but unfortunately the DDI version doesn't seems to change to 11 (which it should be).  I have installed the Extension Pack and the Guest Additions
for my Windows 7 machine.

Do you guys have any suggestion? Im a newbie.

Edit: Here is an information dump from DxDiag: pastebin.com/wTKebAaQ

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate which version of VirtualBox you are using. You performed.  Additionally, `Directx End-User Runtime`, only installs DirectX 9.  Versions after DX9 cannot actually be installed and are built-into Windows.

Comment: @CaoDo - Instead of an unreadable text report can you just provide a screenshot?

Comment: DDI is a property of the display driver. It indicates the DirectX version the display driver supports. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: So I found a solution after 3 weeks. Disable the video acceleration and guest additions, should allow you to use your gpu driver instead of the virtual box driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most recent and newest possible version of Direct X for Windows 7 is Direct X 11.

That is far as you can do with Windows 7.

That would be the same for DDI .  No more updates feasible

**You see if you can reinstall Direct X for Windows 7 from the Microsoft download section, but if that does not work, or support what you want, there is nothing more you can do.**

This is from a Windows 7 Virtual Machine in VMware

This article may help:

[DDI for Windows 7](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/33ba20c8-2cbf-46eb-b4d6-cf06f3f54d06/ddi-version-11?forum=w7itprogeneral)

[image: Direct X for Windows 7]

DDI Version Windows 7

[image: Window 7 DDI]

Comment: yes exactly, Dx 11 is the max version for windows 7 but I think the DDI version should also be 11 too, right?

Comment: I looked up and that was all I could find about DDI and like I said, no updates any more.   See this link   https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/33ba20c8-2cbf-46eb-b4d6-cf06f3f54d06/ddi-version-11?forum=w7itprogeneral

Comment: I added a screen shot showing DDI V11 in my Windows 7 VM.  Try reinstalling Direct X

Comment: "I think the DDI version should also be 11 too, right?" - Depends if you are talking about a physical or virtual machine.  *The capabilities of a virtual machine with regards to DDI will depend on the hypervisor being used. VMWare capabilities are much greater with regards to Vulkan and DX compared to VirtualBox.*

Comment: You would need to try reinstalling Direct X .   That is likely the only option to you.

Comment: @John - How does one reinstall DX11 when it cannot be installed even on Windows 7 and only usable after Windows 7 is fully updated. I suppose that its semantics as to what is actually being installed the update or DX? You have to install the proper display driver to make DXDiag report the correct information.

Comment: Try https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=17431  And otherwise I only see downloads from File Hippo and like. May not be possible.

Comment: @John - You do realize I asked a question I already knew the answer to, right? What you linked to isn’t DirectX 10/11/12, it’s actually, just a presentation.

Comment: I made an error.   Normal for me I suppose. I thought the poster was the author and did not look closely enough.  Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

The key to the mystery must lie in the virtual hardware of the VM.

If the VM was created with an integrated graphics processor (or a GPU)
that only supports up to DirectX 10, then this is what will be reported.

The DirectX API is backwards compatible with older hardware, but it
can only support what the hardware supports.
One cannot make a DirectX 10 GPU into a DirectX 11 GPU just by installing
DirectX 11.

Comment: You also cannot install DirectX 11.  In order to say that statement another way, DirectX 11 is already installed, it's built-into Windows 7 (provided Windows 7 is fully updated) and DirectX 12 is built-into Windows 10 and Windows 11.  Hardware will determine what DirectX Feature Level is useable. A GPU that only supports Feature Level 10_0 cannot use features from Feature Level 12_0 for instance. The only version of DirectX that can be installed is DirectX 9, which can coexists, with DirectX 11 on Windows. **It's only appliciable to legacy applications.**